# What can I do with a setter method that takes no arguments

Tags: ruby

Someone asked whether it was possible to define a setter method that takes more than one argument, but searching around it seems like it's not possible.

I said that setter methods cannot take more than one argument, but then thought about it and was wondering whether I actually could define a setter than takes no arguments:

```
class Test
  def self.args=

  end
end
```

And Ruby accepts it, probably cause there's no reason NOT to accept it. Can I actually do anything with it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it as a setter, and it's not even very useful as a method in general. The only way to even make that method run is to use `send` or create a Method instance, because the normal message-send syntax doesn't allow the message to include a "=" character.

So you technically could have code like this:

```
class Foo
  def bar=()
    puts "Hi, mom!"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.send(:bar=)
```

and it would print "Hi, mom!" as expected.

But can you do anything with it? Well, I guess you could brag to all your friends about your nigh-uncallable setter that doesn't set anything. Beyond that, no, it's really not useful for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything that any other instance method without arguments can do. If you invoke it within the context of the `=` operator, then I don't think you can pass it a block, but you *can* pass it a block via in conjunction with `send`.

Note, though, that your example defines a setter method on the singleton class, whereas setter methods are usually defined as instance methods.